# How to work with the blob error in VsCode

Tags: python, parsing, visual-studio-code, azure-blob-storage, shared-access-signatures

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8s06.jpg)The Error is as shown in the image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I followed the below Steps to download the file from the
> blob storage to local path

- I tried your code and got the same as yours

[image]

- Adding input to @MingJie-MSFT
- Create an Azure Storage account, Container and Upload the file

[image]

- In visual studio code enter the below code, give your [bloburl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPiRi.png) and file name.

[image]

```py
from fileinput import filename
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient


blob_url = "your blob url"
file_name = "hello2.log"

blob_client= BlobClient.from_blob_url(blob_url)
with open(file_name, "wb") as my_blob:
    download_stream= blob_client.download_blob()   
    my_blob.write(download_stream.readall())
```

- Run the code

[image]

Comment: Hello Sampath and Mingjie, Thank you for responding. Can any of you tell me how to work this code while having a SAS URL, blob and container name, file name and a azure.storage.blog._shared_access_signature to connect it and be able to access the log file stored in it. I don't have access to the azure account, it is a task given to me by my superior, i have to do it with the SAS url shared with me

Comment: you need to have Azure account, then you can follow the below image for SAS url.

[Img1] https://i.imgur.com/oCBkvhj.png

[Img2] https://i.imgur.com/lDShvl2.png

Comment: Are you sure sir that i  need to have an Azure account access because I am specifically being told to access the files through the SAS url shared with me without credentials, and connect that in python with blob and container name and file name given to me. I just want clarity, (not doubting your guidance)

Comment: if you want to create an Azure storage account then you need to have the Azure account, if you have an existed SAS URL then you can use it in the code.

Comment: Sir i have been given a SAS  URL but I am not able to understand how to go about it, I've tried different approaches to connect it to the existing storage whose SAS URl has been provided to me but it is not working. Any code you can help me with? I also have blob name and container name with me and the particular file name i am asked to access

Comment: Make sure pick the correct SAS URL from our container and add it in the above code which I provided.
It worked for me!

Comment: Sir, please check the code once in the image i am posting in the edited question above. I was advised to do something with the from azure.storage.blob._shared_access_signature  command and i dont know how to go about it.

Comment: You can find the SAS URL in this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/jKl89O2.png).

Answer (score 0):

The package you imported is incorrect.

The method `from_blob_url` belong to package **BlobClient** instead of BlobServiceClient.

[image]

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
BlobClient.from_blob_url
```